# why suspend operator fun getValue not supported in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Why following signature gives `Unsupported [suspend operator "getValue"]` compilation error?

```
suspend operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T
```

Is it because of any technical limitation?

Answer (score 8):

The `getValue` operator is for implementing the getter of a `val`, and there is no such thing as a `suspend val` -- only a normal `val`.

A `suspend fun` can't be called directly from a normal function, like the implementation of a getter -- so this `getValue` can't be used for its intended purpose.  Kotlin warns you of that by giving a compile error on an attempt to create a `suspend operator fun getValue`.